WiX installer is failing on repair via the msi with `ExecSecureObjects: Error 0x80070534: failed to get sid for account: ...`
I created a WiX installer project that is using PermissionEx, from the WixUtilExtension, to set permissions on folders. The account it uses is passed in from the installer's WPF user interface. The install is working as expected.
What isn't working is performing a repair via the MSI file.  The repair operation does not complete and is rolled back. When I use verbose logging to see what the issue is, I find this in the log file ExecSecureObjects:  Error 0x80070534: failed to get sid for account: {account name}. The {account name} is the actual account name sent to the installer, however, it is not displaying the domain name (in my case the local machine name) that was sent with it during the install, in the Domain\Username format.  I am using the same account for the install and the repair.
I was considering trying to send the domain and username separately as PermissionEx appears to have a Domain attribute, but it works correctly during the install as a combined value.
Note that I have a default value in the property that I used for this, but the defaults for other properties are overridden and work correctly during the repair.
I appreciate any insight that can be provided on this.  Note that I tagged this as WiX3.11, but I am actually using WiX3.14 (there is no tag for that).
Thank you.
